# Can i Print the structure as it sends to C++ Using ffi-napi approche with Unmanaged DLL

Tags: electron, ffi

I am using following libraries: **ref-struct-di, ref-napi, ref-array-di**
in order to build struct for C++ DLL, but when I try to log (console log) the struct I get object with buffer instead of struct that I build for C++ DLL.

How I can get the structure as it sends to C++ without adding log inside C++ DLL?

***Example code:***

```
import array from 'ref-array-di';
import ref from 'ref-napi';
import StructType from 'ref-struct-di';

const structFactory = StructType(ref);

const doubleArray = arrayFactory(ref.types.double);

const intArray = arrayFactory(ref.types.int32);

const bufferVectorector = structFactory({
    items: doubleArray,
    size: intArray,
    allocatedSize: ref.types.int32,
    numDimensions: ref.types.int32,
    canFreeData: ref.types.bool
});

const scanBufferStruct = structFactory({
    cw: ref.refType(bufferVectorector),
    tg: ref.refType(bufferVectorector)
});

const scanBuffer = new scanBufferStruct({
    cw: createVectorDouble(scanBufferCw, 'Nx1').ref(),
    tg: createVectorDouble(scanBufferTg, 'Nx1').ref()
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(scanBuffer.toObject()));
```